# SQLSTATE[42000]: 1142 TRIGGER command denied for table 'catalog_product_index_price_replica',

Tags: database, reindex, magento2.3.3

Good Day

I am very much a novice when it comes to this. I upgraded my store from Magento 2.2.8 to 2.3.3.

All seemed initially to go without issues.

However on reindexing i get the below error.

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 TRIGGER command denied to user 'mydatabaseusername' for table 'catalog_product_index_price_replica', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_replica` (`entity_id`, `customer_group_id`, `website_id`, `tax_class_id`, `price`, `final_price`, `min_price`, `max_price`, `tier_price`) SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.`price`, `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.`final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_temp`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_temp` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `customer_group_id` = VALUES(`customer_group_id`), `website_id` = VALUES(`website_id`), `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`)

The reindex appears to be attempting to use "mydatabaseusername" which is my old username and this is throwing the error.

I have checked app/etc/env.php and database name, username and password are correct.

All other reindexs are successful.

I have cleared and flushed cache.

I have search the internet and cant seem to find anyone with a similar problem.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following steps will help you.

1. Export `catalog_product_index_price_replica` table.
2. find `database user name` which is not related to current `database`.
3. replace old dbuser to current dbuser.
4. Take database backup.
5. drop `catalog_product_index_price_replica` and Import last modified .sql file

reference [chage privillages](https://serverfault.com/questions/565343/how-to-grant-and-revoke-rights-to-tables-using-phpmyadmin)

Thank you.

Comment: thanks that worked